# Java Embedded, after insert I cannot recheck if the row exists

Tags: java, derby

I am inserting a row in Java Derby Embedded database. Immediately I am rechecking whether the row with the particular ID exists. The code I use works fine elsewhere in Sqlite3, MySql etc. But in Derby it throws an error, invalid cursor state, no current row.( But the row is added and exists) What is that I am doing wrong?

```
String sql="";                      
     stmt = conn.createStatement();
     sql = "INSERT INTO USERLIST (UserID,UserName,PaWord,RealName) " +
                    "VALUES (" + Nextam + ",'" + f1 + "','" + f2 + "','" + f3 + "')"; 
     stmt.executeUpdate(sql);


     stmt.close();

     Thread.sleep(1000);

// rechecking

stmt = conn.createStatement();


rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM USERLIST where UserID=" + Nextam + "" );

    String  nameR = rs.getString("RealName");

    if(nameR.length() < 2){
      System.out.println( "Seems like Error " + Nextam );
    }else{ 
      String infum=nameR + " Added as " + Nextam;
      ShowLab(infum);
    }


    stmt.close();

    conn.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call `rs.next()` after you performed the `stmt.executeQuery()` call.

Are you **sure** this code works on other systems?